# Solving for a single variable across multiple equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have these three equations here:

```
Log10[f/(1 - f)] == pH - pKa + F Vs/(2.3 R T)
σM == cF VF
Ee - Epzc == VF + Vs
```

and I would like to have *Mathematica* put `σM` in terms of `f`.  The obvious thing for a human to do would be to solve equation 1 for `Vs`, put that solution for `Vs` into equation 3 and solve for `VF`, and then finally put that solution for `VF` into equation 2.  Is there a command or code snippet that would do this for me?

Comment: Please do not use `E` as a variable, as that is reserved for $e=2.71828\dots$ in *Mathematica*. Anyway, look up `Eliminate[]`.

Comment: Good point, I'll change that to avoid confusion.  That isn't exactly my code that I used, I had just edited it to look more presentable.

Comment: Try `Solve[{Log10[f/(1 - f)] == pH - pKa + F Vs/(2.3 R T), σM == cF VF, Ee - Epzc == VF + Vs}, σM, {Vs, VF}]`

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly it.  What's the logic for putting {Vs, VF} there at the end?  I see that the third parameter for Solve is a domain, but I'm not sure how {Vs,VF} can be the domain.  Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: By the way: "I'll change that to avoid confusion"? Really, you should change that to avoid being *wrong*, because *Mathematica* is going to interpret that as the number $e$ no matter what.

Comment: This isn't exactly the code I'm using.  I had just edited it to look more presentable in this post.  I already changed it anyway, so not sure what your comment's purpose is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a time, [`Solve[]` had the following documented syntax](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/AlgebraicComputation/EquationSolving/Solve.html):

> `Solve[eqns, vars, elims]` attempts to solve the equations for `vars`, eliminating the variables `elims`.

Altho this syntax has been superseded by the third argument now being a domain specification, this older syntax seems to have been retained for backwards compatibility. Thus, to solve for `σM` in your system of equations, while getting rid of the intermediate variables `Vs` and `VF`, you can do this:

```
Solve[{Log10[f/(1 - f)] == pH - pKa + F Vs/(2.3 R T), σM == cF VF,
       Ee - Epzc == VF + Vs}, σM, {Vs, VF}]
   {{σM -> (1.*cF*(1.*Ee*F - 1.*Epzc*F + 2.3*pH*R*T - 2.3*pKa*R*T -
            0.998877*R*T*Log[f/(1. - 1.*f)]))/F}}
```

(I do not make any guarantees on whether this deprecated syntax will remain in future versions, however.)

Comment: Thanks for the clear and thorough explanation.  If I wanted to do this again in 5 years when that syntax has finally been removed, would the equivalent be: `Solve[Eliminate[equations, {Vs, VF}], σM]`?

Comment: That would be the somewhat circuitous route, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I like the deprecated syntax; it's conceptually clearer and, if you only want to solve for a limited no. of variables, makes for a cleaner output.  However, I've found that same functionality (the ability to eliminate designated unknowns) is found in the current syntax (at least in v 11.2).

Specifically, I've found that, if you have  an underdetermined system, (i.e., n independent equations with at least n+1 unknowns), and specify exactly n of the unknowns in the list of variables, then Solve will attempt to solve for those n variables while simultaneously eliminating them from *all* of the resulting expressions. I.e., If Solve provides an output, it will express those variables as dependent only.  For example, the following gives expressions for x, y, and c as functions of some or all of the remaining unknowns (d, z, and b) only:

```
Solve[x + 2 y + 3 z == 4 b c && 3 x + 4 y + 5 z == 6 && 
6 x + 7 y + 8 z + d == 9, {x, y, c}]
```

Likewise, considering your problem, the following gives expressions for σM, Vs, and VF as functions of some or all of the remaining unknowns only:

```
Solve[Log10[f/(1 - f)] == pH - pKa + F Vs/(2.3 R T) && σM == 
cF VF && Ee - Epzc == VF + Vs, {σM, Vs, VF}]
```

This obviates the need for Solve[Eliminate[equations, {Vs, VF}], σM].

We can compare the expression the current syntax gives for σM with that from the deprecated syntax; you can see they're identical (I replaced 2.3 with 23/10 to give cleaner output and thus facilitate the comparison):

```
Solve[
Log10[f/(1 - f)] == pH - pKa + F Vs/(23/10 R T) && σM == 
cF VF && Ee - Epzc == VF + Vs, {σM, Vs, VF}]//Simplify

Solve[
Log10[f/(1 - f)] == pH - pKa + F Vs/(23/10 R T) && σM == 
cF VF && Ee - Epzc == VF + Vs, {σM}, {Vs, VF}]//Simplify
```

What I've described above (for the current syntax) works for all examples I've tested.  However, I don't know if this behavior holds generally.  Perhaps someone with deeper knowledge of MMA's underlying structure than I have can comment.